# Is passing by use of parameter necessary for data type int to prevent sql injection

Tags: .net, sql-injection

as per question once more:
Do we really need to pass numbers datatype variable values as parameters to prevent sql injection.

I do have two sample function one with parameter and next without using parameter

```
function CheckThis(int UIN)
{
  var connect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NorthWind"].ToString();
  var query = "Select * From Products Where ProductID = @ProductID";
  using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
  {
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.Int);
      cmd.Parameters["@ProductID"].Value = UIN;
      conn.Open();
      //Process results
    }
  }
}
```

OR is following ok

```
function CheckThis(int UIN)
{
  var connect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NorthWind"].ToString();
  var query = "Select * From Products Where ProductID = " + UIN;
  using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
  {
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
      //cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.Int);
      //cmd.Parameters["@ProductID"].Value = UIN;
      conn.Open();
      //Process results
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do it to stop SQL injection attacks<sup>1</sup>. However:

- Your code is cleaner if you separate the SQL from the values
- If the type is later changed from `int` to something else, you would *then* be at risk of an injection attack, and it's entirely possible that it would be missed in code review
- It avoids any issues with number-to-string conversions involving unexpected thousands separators etc

In short, I would definitely still use parameters.

---

<sup>1</sup> Unless your attacker can also affect your locale settings. At that point, [even string concatenation with integers can be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/08/08/the-bobbytables-culture/).

Comment: gr8... listing of advantages of using it

Comment: I wonder if it's the same for decimal, bignum, and floating-point types?

Comment: @Panzercrisis: Yes, absolutely. Parameterization is simply the way to go.

Comment: Are they able to be hacked?

Comment: @Panzercrisis: Not with SQL injection attacks, no... the whole point is that you're specifying the value in a separate way from the SQL.

Comment: I mean, can they get hacked if they're not passed in that way, or are they in the same boat as integer types?

Comment: @Panzercrisis: Ah. They're mostly as *safe* as integer types, unless someone can change your culture settings ([in which case you're in trouble](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/08/08/the-bobbytables-culture/)) but they're more likely to suffer from conversion issues.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Thanks, this answer deserves more upvotes!